# Вывод данных некорректно выходить record.append(worksheet.cell(x,y).value)

Tags: python, excel

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(unicode("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Таблица.xlsx", "utf-8"))
worksheet= workbook.sheet_by_name(unicode("Лист1", "utf-8"))

total_rows= worksheet.nrows
total_cols= worksheet.ncols

table = list()
record =list() 


for x in range(total_rows):
    for y in range(total_cols):
        record.append(worksheet.cell(x,y).value)
    table.append(record)
    record=[]
    x +=1


print(table)
```

Comment: укажите в вопросе суть проблемы. Если есть ошибка - приведите полный `error traceback`...

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите получить список списков, содержащий значения ячеек (внутренние списки) для каждой строки (внешний список), то можно воспользоваться Pandas (по-умолчанию Pandas использует `xlrd` для чтения Excel файлов):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(u"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Таблица.xlsx")
table = df.values.tolist()
```

Пример:

```
In [84]: df = pd.read_excel(u'd:/temp/test.xlsx')

In [85]: df
Out[85]:
     a    b    c
0  aaa  1.1  100
1  bbb  2.2  200
2  ccc  3.3  300

In [86]: df.dtypes
Out[86]:
a     object
b    float64
c      int64
dtype: object

In [87]: df.values.tolist()
Out[87]: [['aaa', 1.1, 100], ['bbb', 2.2, 200], ['ccc', 3.3, 300]]
```